# ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.18.1 with JDK 17

Tags: activemq-classic

While attempting to use ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.18.1 with JDK 17 we encountered some errors during the startup process. The documentation indicated that this version of ActiveMQ should be compatible with JDK 11 and higher. However, despite meeting the compatibility requirements, the following errors were encountered while starting ActiveMQ. These errors indicate that there may be compatibility issues between ActiveMQ 5.18.1 and JDK 17.

Below is how we are starting ActiveMQ

```
./activemq console
```

```
2023-06-26T16:30:15.266950813Z INFO: Loading '/opt/activemq//bin/env'
2023-06-26T16:30:15.268183358Z INFO: Using java '/usr/jdk-17.0.7+7/bin/java'
2023-06-26T16:30:15.269974321Z INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
2023-06-26T16:30:15.269988755Z INFO: Creating pidfile /opt/activemq//data/activemq.pid
2023-06-26T16:30:16.377906222Z  INFO | Error when creating PropertyDescriptor for public final void org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.setProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)! Ignoring this property.
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828054047Z ERROR | Failed to load: URL file:/opt/activemq/conf/activemq.xml, reason: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL file:/opt/activemq/conf/camel.xml; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828085004Z org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL file:/opt/activemq/conf/camel.xml; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828118085Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:417) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828120590Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828122545Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828125880Z     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:143) ~[xbean-spring-4.22.jar:4.22]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828127720Z     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:109) ~[xbean-spring-4.22.jar:4.22]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828129563Z     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:95) ~[xbean-spring-4.22.jar:4.22]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828131860Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828133744Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828135503Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828137184Z     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:79) ~[xbean-spring-4.22.jar:4.22]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828138960Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828140760Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828142482Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828144286Z     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:116) ~[xbean-spring-4.22.jar:4.22]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828145990Z     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:104) ~[xbean-spring-4.22.jar:4.22]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828147892Z     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828149599Z     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:671) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828151234Z     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828153403Z     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64) ~[xbean-spring-4.22.jar:4.22]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828155267Z     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52) ~[xbean-spring-4.22.jar:4.22]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828161175Z     at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104) ~[activemq-spring-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828163200Z     at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104) [activemq-spring-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828165059Z     at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67) [activemq-spring-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828169634Z     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71) [activemq-broker-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828171620Z     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:98) [activemq-broker-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828178868Z Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828188001Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:81) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828190217Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:125) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828191997Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$GetterSetterReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:402) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828193818Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.<init>(TransducedAccessor.java:235) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828195566Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(TransducedAccessor.java:175) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828197246Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.AttributeProperty.<init>(AttributeProperty.java:91) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828199246Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:108) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828201535Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828203179Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:503) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828204963Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:168) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828206678Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:503) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828208726Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:168) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828210405Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:503) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828212047Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:320) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828213798Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828215555Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1138) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828217927Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828224609Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:286) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828227790Z     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828230560Z     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828233839Z     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828237035Z     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828239974Z     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:186) ~[jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828242711Z     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146) ~[jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828245351Z     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:350) ~[jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828248006Z     at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:446) ~[jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828250841Z     at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:409) ~[jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828253457Z     at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModelJAXBContextFactory.newJAXBContext(DefaultModelJAXBContextFactory.java:31) ~[camel-core-2.25.4.jar:2.25.4]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828266866Z     at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.getJaxbContext(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:206) ~[camel-spring-2.25.4.jar:2.25.4]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828270657Z     at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:368) ~[camel-spring-2.25.4.jar:2.25.4]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828275631Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:88) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828454798Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:63) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828465113Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828470434Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828473366Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1371) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828476680Z     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:98) ~[xbean-spring-4.22.jar:4.22]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828480031Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828482614Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828485668Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828488439Z     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:79) ~[xbean-spring-4.22.jar:4.22]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828491320Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828493969Z     ... 26 more
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828519048Z Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @3bf7ca37
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828526059Z     at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828528892Z     at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828532313Z     at java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828535120Z     at java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828538130Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.getMethod(Injector.java:184) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828540855Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.access$000(Injector.java:69) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828544572Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1.run(Injector.java:168) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828547422Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1.run(Injector.java:165) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828550181Z     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828553031Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.<clinit>(Injector.java:164) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828555823Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:81) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828558706Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:125) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828564012Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$GetterSetterReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:402) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828566893Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.<init>(TransducedAccessor.java:235) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828569745Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(TransducedAccessor.java:175) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828572434Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.AttributeProperty.<init>(AttributeProperty.java:91) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828575073Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:108) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828577671Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828580489Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:503) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828614904Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:168) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828618999Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:503) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828621781Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:168) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828624437Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:503) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828627136Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:320) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828630252Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828638854Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1138) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828641861Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828644654Z     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:286) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828647212Z     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828649809Z     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828652958Z     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828671812Z     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828675065Z     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:186) ~[jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828677885Z     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146) ~[jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828680519Z     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:350) ~[jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828683262Z     at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:446) ~[jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828685624Z     at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:409) ~[jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:?]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828688173Z     at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModelJAXBContextFactory.newJAXBContext(DefaultModelJAXBContextFactory.java:31) ~[camel-core-2.25.4.jar:2.25.4]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828690888Z     at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.getJaxbContext(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:206) ~[camel-spring-2.25.4.jar:2.25.4]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828693881Z     at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:368) ~[camel-spring-2.25.4.jar:2.25.4]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828696713Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:88) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828699268Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:63) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828702112Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828704879Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828707430Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1371) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828710483Z     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:98) ~[xbean-spring-4.22.jar:4.22]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828713212Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828715838Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828718467Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828726094Z     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:79) ~[xbean-spring-4.22.jar:4.22]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828728965Z     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
2023-06-26T16:30:17.828731799Z     ... 26 more
```

Comment: When I start ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.18.1 with JDK 17 (i.e. `openjdk 17.0.7 2023-04-18`) and the default `activemq.xml` everything works fine. There must be something different between your environment and mine. Are you using the default `activemq.xml`?

Comment: I've also had no issue running the 5.18.1 broker on a JDK 17 install.

Comment: Yes there are some customisations to activemq.xml which creates some new queues and topics

Comment: Also we have integrated with camel for routing.

Comment: You need to provide more details on how to reproduce this failure otherwise your question may be closed.

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace, it looks like you're trying to fire up Camel. We also previously ran our Camel routes as part of the ActiveMQ broker (5.17.x series), but in order to upgrade to JDK 17 and ActiveMQ 5.18.x, we had to move our Camel Routes to an external application that connects to the ActiveMQ Broker. (This is actually the recommended architecture from the Camel Documentation).

There are two reasons why we had to do this per their documentation: https://endoflife.date/apache-camel

- Camel 2.x is End of Life over a year ago and is no longer receiving security updates
- Camel 2.x only supports up to JDK 8 (although we did manage to run it with JDK 11)

So starting an ActiveMQ broker in JDK17 with embedded Camel 2.x simply isn't going to work. Camel 2.x was never enhanced to be compatible with the modularization changes in JDK 17+. The latest Camel 3.x is not integrated into ActiveMQ server, but does support JDK17. We ended up converting our Camel routes to v3.21 and running them in a Quarkus container under JDK17.

I don't think I've seen anyone make the effort to convert Camel 2.x to run under JDK17. It wouldn't be impossible, but by the time you enhanced the Camel framework to support JDK17 you might as well converted your routes to Camel 3.x.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note: Camel running embedded w/ a broker is a massive performance optimization. Moving to a remote architecture is not recommended for use cases where low latency and high throughput are needed. Also, future versions of ActiveMQ 5.18.x may upgrade to Camel v3.x to better support JDK 17 ref: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-9290

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's very useful. Now we need to examine if we're on LTS or not, could be important.